# Double Head Slider Input is not picking up all the values in a Range in R

Tags: r, shiny, uislider, shinydashboard

I am trying to design a reactive Shiny Application. I am using a Double Headed Slider Input for picking up multiple values and to display it's corresponding other column values in a data table in Shiny App. The issue which I am facing is for example lets take the range as 1 to 3, Where my data has values for 1, 2 and 3. When I place one Input dot in 1 and another Input dot in 3, the general expectation is, it should pick up the values for 2 also, as it is present in the range of 1 to 3. But the values of 2 are not getting displayed. Kindly find the code which I used to create a Slider Input.

```
sliderInput(
                  "key",
                  "Key Value",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 3,
                  value = c(1,3),
                  step=1
                )
```

And in the Shiny App the Slider Input values are selected like this.

[image]

The Output which I am getting is

[image]

But I should be getting the values of 2 also.

Can someone please help me on this.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Actually I have tried both `c(1:3)` and `c(1,3)`. Its giving me the same results. That the value of 2 is not getting picked.

Comment: Can you also include some example code showing how you filter the data with this input?

Comment: It would be great to have a look at the whole app. If that’s not possible at least show us the server side where you use the slideinput values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect that the error is not in your slider, but in the way you filter. Note that a slider returns the minimum and maximum values selected, and not all values in its range. So here,`input$key` would return an array with the numbers and 1 and 3, and not 2. If you would then subsequently apply the filter `df$Key %in% input$key`, only 1's and 3's would be selected. If you want all numbers within the range, you should filter for the numbers in between, for example

```
df$Key >= input$key[1] & df$Key <= input$key[2]
```

or

```
df$Key %inrange% input$key,
```

with `%inrange%` from the `data.table` package.

A working example is given below, hope this helps!

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(data.table)

df <- data.frame(Key=c(1,1,2,2,3,3))

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("key","Key Value",min = 1,max = 3,value = c(1,3),step=1),
  dataTableOutput('my_dt')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$my_dt <- renderDataTable({
    # produces wrong result; only 1 and 3.
    # df <- df[df$numbers %in% input$key,,drop=FALSE]
    # produces correct result; 1,2 and 3.
    # df <- df[df$Key %inrange% input$key,,drop=FALSE]
    # Also produces correct result; 1,2 and 3. No data.table needed.
    df <- df[df$Key >= input$key[1] & df$Key <= input$key[2],,drop=FALSE]
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) Now I am able to select all the values in the Range. You are Awesome !!!